# Generic Validation Using Jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, validation

I am trying to write an javascript validations as generic. I have added an attribute for all the controls that are mandated for a page. When ever any button click happens (Post action) I have a client side script that will run and it will check is there any mandatory control that is not filled with data. If so then it will create an alert message like 'Please enter the value'.

So here is the actual problem. whenever I try with `Asp:checkbox` and `asp:radio` it always render with span control without any ID attribute. So I am not able to pick up the checkbox or radio button control using the span Control using Jquery.

Here is the code in the server side that will assign `isMandated=true` based on the business validation.

control.Attributes.Add("isMandatory", "true")

Here control is the `webcontrol`

here is the rendered output of `Asp:checkbox` and `asp:radio`

```
<span isMandatory="true"><input id="mainHolder_rdb1" type="radio" name="ctl00$mainHolder$rdb1" value="rdb1" /></span>

<span isMandatory="true"><input id="mainHolder_chkBox" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$mainHolder$chkBox" /></span>
```

Here i am not able to pick up the control using span control without ID attribute. Is there any workaround to solve this.(But I have idea of using client control by adding the runat="server" tag)

Here is my actual javascript code,

```
function validateMandatedFields() {
var isValid = true;
var tagName = "";
    $("[ismandatory='true']").each(function (ctrl) {
        thisControl = $(this);
        tagName = thisControl.prop('tagName').toLowerCase();

        if (tagName === "select" && thisControl.val() === "-1") {
            alert("please enter the value");
            thisControl.focus();
            isValid = false;
            return isValid;
        }
        else if ((tagName === "table") && $("#" + thisControl.attr("id") + " input[type='radio']").length > 0) {
            var isChecked = $("#" + thisControl.attr("id") + " input[type='radio']").is(":checked");
            if (!isChecked) {
                alert("please select any option");
                $("#" + thisControl.attr("id") + " input[type='radio']").focus();
                isValid = false;
                return isValid;
            }
        }
        else if ((tagName === "table") && $("#" + thisControl.attr("id") + " input[type='checkbox']").length > 0) {
            var isChecked = $("#" + thisControl.attr("id") + " input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked");
            if (!isChecked) {
                alert("please select any option");
                $("#" + thisControl.attr("id") + " input[type='checkbox']").focus();
                isValid = false;
                return isValid;
            }
        } else if (tagName === "span" && $("span input[type='checkbox']").length>0) {
            var isChecked = $("span input[type='checkbox']").is(":checked");
            if (!isChecked) {
                alert("please select any option");
                $("span input[type='checkbox']").focus();
                isValid = false;
                return isValid;
            }
        }
        else if (tagName === "span" && $("span input[type='radio']").length > 0) {

            var isChecked = $("span input[type='radio']").is(":checked");
            if (!isChecked) {
                alert("please select any option");
                $("span input[type='radio']").focus();
                isValid = false;
                return isValid;
            }
        }
        else if (thisControl.val() === "") {
            alert("please enter the value");
            thisControl.focus();
            isValid = false;
            return isValid;
        }
    });
    return isValid;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look on Jquery Validate plugin? http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Yeah I already looked into that. But it seems to be lot of changes I have to do for every pages to create the rules. I do have more than 25 controls in a page.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I came to an Idea to include another one attribute like 'ControlToValidate' and its value as 'Control.ClientID'.

And this one will be added to the controls like asp:CheckBox and asp:radioButton.